# tab bar item don't recive variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

first of all, i'm using storyboard.
i first created a viewcontroller controlled by one class, and in this view ther is a textfield where the user puts a number, a button uses modal to take the user to a tabbar controller with two itens "one" and "two", "one" and "two" takes us to different viewcontrollers (controlled by the same class), but both  with a label, this label have to  present the value that user put in the textfield at the first view... i only know how to do that by:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:[mytextfield.text intValue] forKey:@"integerKey"];
```

in one class, and:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger mynumber = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

NSString *mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", mynumber];
mylabelonone.text = mystring;
mylabelontwo.text = mystring;
```

in the other class...

but, when i test it in the simulator, and click the button that takes us to "one" the label is empty, even so, when i click the item that goes to "two", the label is there with the exact number!

I tried to change "one" and "two" order in the tabbar controller and then the problem happens with "two" and one is perfect!

I don't have any idea of what can be happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table View Controllers work in an interesting way. When switching between between tabs, methods such as  `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillDisappear`.

So the question becomes where you are putting the lines of code posted. That code will work, but only if the first code is run before the user taps a different tab, and the second part of your code runs after the first.

`– tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` and `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`

Another way would be to import a view and then set a variable from the second view while still in the first.